# to run a heavy background job in tomcat and track its progress

Tags: java, jsp, tomcat

In my tomcat website, a user will upload inputs in excels . The number of excels is about 4 to 5. And then the website should process these excels to generate invoice.
Since, it is a heavy process , how to create a background task trigger by a button click at jsp page and track its progress by progress bar in another jsp page , and render a success or failure jsp page.

Comment: Did you try anything yet? Do you know how to store data like progress on the server (e.g. in the session) and read it again? Do you know how to start tasks/threads on tomcat?

Comment: no, I am novice in tomcat  aand j2ee but knows  core java

Comment: See http://www.javabeat.net/asynchronous-servlet-servlet-3-0/